# Transmission Damages

Tags: chevrolet, transmission-fluid

Had a Guy change my trans Fluid,But not the torque Converter and he still added 10quarts,now some fluid leaking out a hole,and now my chevy drive weird when accelerating or slowing Down

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I realize there was too much transmission fluid put into the vehicle, what exactly is your question here? You state you have a "chevy", but you don't tell us what the year/model/engine/transmission is in your Chevrolet. Can you please edit your question and put some more information in it for us? Also, what's stopping you from taking it back to the "guy" and having them fix their mistake?